# APNS Invalid token error using Parse

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS app in Xcode 7 that used Push Notifications via Parse in development mode. I had to format my Mac’s hard drive and reinstall El Capitan and Xcode. Running my same old code, all my push notifications now get a “APNS Invalid token” error. I’m assuming the error is due to changes on my Mac.

I have revoked and replaced my APN certificate at the Apple Member Center, downloaded the new certificate, put in it my keychain, exported it to a p12, deleted my old certificate at Parse and installed the new p12 file. I also edited and renewed my Provisioning Profile at Apple.

I’m still getting the Invalid token error from Apple. I haven’t changed any other settings so I don’t believe I am trying to use a development token against Apple’s production Push notifications service, or vise-versa.

Can anyone suggest how to correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because Xcode cannot find a correct provisioning profile linked with with your app Bundle identifier and it is relying on its default profile. 
In the menu go to: `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts`
Then click on `View Details..` button to see all the provisioning profile associated with your account. Make sure you download them all so that Xcode can find them on your disk. Alternatively you can download your provisioning profiles from member centre on your mac and double click on them so that Xcode loads them internally.

Comment: The Provisioning Profiles with this App Bundle Identifier seem to be present, their expiration dates are in the future, but they do no have Download buttons in their Action fields. I assume this means they are already downloaded?

Comment: I went to Apple and downloaded and double-clicked all Provisioning Profiles with this App ID. I'm still getting the Invalid token error.

Comment: When you install your app did you get fresh installation record in Installation class ?

Comment: I deleted all Installations, Sessions and Users from the Parse database.

Comment: When I first recompiled the project there was a code-signing issue. I clicked the Fix Issue button and the build completed. After I discovered the Push Notification issue I went in and fiddled with the signing selections. Upon building this caused another code-signing issue. I clicked Fix, Xcode restored its preferred values and the build completed. I haven't changed any signing values since then.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-enable Push Notifications in the apps Capabilities.